# Download and zip files in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, zip, jszip

I have an application that stores consultations for users. The consultation has data about the user and has documents attached to the consultation. My goal is to return all documents that were attached to a consultation in a zip to the user. Pretty straight forward.

We have a 5 second timeout restriction. Originally I was thinking we could just download the files and zip them on the server side. That way I could just make a new endpoint that returned the zip to the user. But because of the 5 second time out that may not work.

So I'm looking into downloading and zipping the files on the client side. The front end is built in React and I've been looking into using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). Although almost everything I've found that uses JSZip is using it on the server side.

Is it possible to download and zip files on the client side using React? Is there a library that I could use? Or should this all be on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsZip on Client Side.
For example, if you want to download an image, you need its url.
Then, do a request with axios.
Like this:

```
request = (currentUrl: string): Promise<void> => axios({
    url: currentUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob',
}).then((response) => {
    const url: string = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
});
```

then use the url that axios gave you in response to download your file

Comment: To use Jszip in client side, map on the file list you want to zip and add `response.data` to your JSZip for each file of your lis

Comment: Cool. I finally got JSZip to work. Is it possible to download files from a server and then zip it on the client side using JSZip?

Comment: Yes, you just need to make the same ajax request from server side